# Unity - Visual Studio 2017 Unity Syntax Highlighting not working anymore

Tags: unity, visual-studio

Everything worked perfectly fine yesterday. But today the syntax hightlighting stopped working:

[image: Syntax Highlighting]

`MonoBehaviour` and `Sprite` should be green, just like Item. What can I try to solve this?

**What I tried**: Turned computer on and off.

---

I temporarly solve it by deleting all VS files in my project folder

But If I move a script inside Unity to another folder and then open that script, then Intelli Sense does not work anymore and I have to close Visual Studio, delete all VS files in my project folder again and open the file again in unity. This seems to be a major VS bug.

Comment: There is no solution in that duplicate.

Comment: It appears to me that the questions are about the same issue.

Comment: @Black The lack of an accepted solution has no bearing on whether or not a question is considered a duplicate. It's possible one of the offered solutions does solve the problem & the OP never bothered to mark it (there are a surprising # of abandoned questions). If none of those solutions work for you, upvote it &/or offer a bounty & it may receive more attention.

Comment: I know, thank you. I think the only thing I can do is to wait until VS and UNITY fixed the bug.